# Android jUnit test error

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I wrote the following test class in a package named "com.example.test". I included in the manifest the following instrumentation:

but when I run it as an Android jUnit Test, I get the following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class com.example.test.TestCase has no public     constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Can you help me, please? Thank you :)

```
import com.example.MenuPage;
import com.example.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestCase extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MenuPage>  {

Intent mLaunchIntent;

public TestCase(Class<MenuPage> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mLaunchIntent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),     MenuPage.class);
    startActivity(mLaunchIntent, null, null);
    final Button launchNextButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

@MediumTest
public void testNextActivityWasLaunchedWithIntent() {
    startActivity(mLaunchIntent, null, null);
    final Button launchNextButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    launchNextButton.performClick();

    final Intent launchIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();
    assertNotNull("Intent was null", launchIntent);
    assertTrue(isFinishCalled());

}
```

}

Comment: The error message seems very clear to me - it's expecting a public constructor either without any parameters, or just with a String parameter. How are you expecting the class parameter to be provided to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class com.example.test.TestCase has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()

As this error message says, you *must* provide either a no-arg constructor or one that takes a `String` arg. For example you can do the following:

```
public TestCase() {
    super(MenuPage.class);
}
```